# Why I can't get two values with two variables in a python for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following doubt

First code:

```
x= 'ab'
y = 'cd'
z = 'ef'

for i,j in x,y :
    print (i,j)

>>> Output : a b
             c d
```

> Variable 'i' is : a c , and variable 'j' is : b d

Second code:

```
x= 'ab'
y = 'cd'
z = 'ef'

for i,j in x,y,z:
    print (i,j)

>>> Output : a b
             c d
             e f
```

> Variable 'i' is : a c e, and variable 'j' : b d f

. . and so on.

Now look this:

```
x= 'ab'
y = 'cd'
z = 'ef'

for i,j in x :
    print (i,j)

>>> Output : error not enough values to unpack
```

Why I can't get : a b , where :

> Variable 'i' is : a, and variable 'j' : b

Im very confused.

Comment: Try `for i,j in [x] :
    print (i,j)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "in x" iterates through the string, *as a string*.  The first iteration returns `a`; the second returns `b`.  Each single character is "not enough values to unpack".  Simply

```
i, j = x
```

works as you want.  Note that, in the other loops, you iterated through a *tuple* of strings; this is not the same as iterating through a single string.

Answer (score 1):

In the first piece of code, you iterate on the tuple of strings `(x, y)` (you didn't write the parentheses, but the comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses).

So it boils down to:

```
for two_letters_string in (x, y):
    ...
```

You do a second thing here: instead of `two_letters_string`, you used a tuple `(i, j)` as variable. So, Python will unpack the two letters string, and the first letter ends up in `i`, the second in `j`.

The same happens in the second piece of code. You just have one more loop and iterate on one more string.

The last piece of code is very different: you don't iterate on a tuple of strings, but on a string made of 2 characters. Iterating on a string iterates on its characters, so it will yield `'a'` on the first loop and `'b'` on the second. But you try to unpack these one-character strings into two variables `i` and `j`, which is not possible.

Note that this works:

```
x = 'ab'


for i, j in x, :  # Note the comma after x!
    print (i, j)
    
# a b
```

as the comma after `x` creates a tuple of one item. You are in the same situation as in the first two cases, but with only one loop here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```py
x = 'ab'
y = 'cd'
z = 'ef'

i, j = x
print(i, j)
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap the string into a tuple and a list. Iteration over a single element of a list, that is a tuple of an iterable, is pointless. Just use `i, j = x` without the extra layers.

Answer (score 0):

that's happening because you are given on the loop 2 items i, j

try this now:

```
x= 'ab'
y = 'cd'
z = 'ef'

for i in x :
   print (i)
```